# Push notification issue with Firebase in IOS 10?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, firebase-realtime-database, apple-push-notifications

I am using Firebase server to send Push Notification to **Live App Store build**. I in following situations:

1. I was getting notification some period of time and stop from day.
2. But, i am getting all Push on my iPhone(By App Store Build) but my clients not getting notification.

**My Questions:**

1. I got some Push on Device and stop now,Does it mean my .p12 certificates wrong?

2.I think i submitted build to App Store using Ad Hoc Provisioning profile this could cause issue to some devices to stop notification?

3. My server team using Python language to send Push something use of Lamda causing issue(Server Side)?
4. Is this DeviceToken/ FCM issue?

5.How to make work the notification to **Live App Store build** install by customer?

How to fix this? Any help will much much appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

Generate new certificates, add them to firebase, fix them within the app ,submit new build.

Comment: If the app is already in the app store and push was working then there is no need to create a new build and resubmit to the app store. If push certificates have expired the app still does not need to be rebuilt even if they have.

Comment: As i understood, he uploaded build with wrong certificates? probably only development ones?

Comment: Thats not possible. You think Apple would permit a build signed with development profiles to released to the app store?

Comment: So lets say his app id didnt have push notification setup and he uploaded build to app store, then he decides to fix apns and create new certificates u dont have to do new build ?

Comment: If the app id did not have push notification set up in the first place then push would never ever have worked to begin with. The Op says push does or did use to work for an app store build. The push certificate that is used on the server to sign the pushes can and does become invalid, when this happens it is only necessary to generate new ones and use them on the server. It does not require an app change.

Comment: Dude im not a novice, all im saying that he may have not setup the production certificate to begin with, cuz he is accepting push notifications on his phone but his clients doesnt. Including this if he didnt setup production apns  plz answer my question above, does or doesnt need to setup new build if he didnt have a production apns on the first place. ???!!!

Comment: If he didn't enable push in the app id for production then he would need to rebuild but the OP also says that he can get push with an app store build. An app store build is a production build, also he states he was getting notification some period of time and stop from today. Hence if the op is to be believed when he says he received push on an app store build then apns for the app id for production must have been enabled.

Comment: Yeah ur right, i didnt see, the part () .."  my iPhone(By App Store Build) but my clients not getting notification." I supposed he has that problem most of new ppl have, they forget to properly setup production certificate cuz they mainly use dev one for testing and stuff.

Comment: I guess its possible your track of thinking is actually correct and he submitted a production build with apns not enabled for production and when he says its working for him for an app store build he is mistaken and he has not actually tested it on an app store build but on something he mistakenly thinks is an app store build (i.e. is testing on a local built .ipa which is actually dev but he thinks is prod, and hasn't tried installing the app from the actual app store to confirm).

Answer (score 0):

1) The push certificate expires after a year. Have you been to the Apple provisioning portal to see if it is still valid? If not, regenerate new ones for use with the server. You do not need to rebuild the app.

2) There is only one type of build provisioning that can be submitted to the App store. You think Apple will not check what is being submitted? You cannot have submitted anything that is not intended to be submitted

3)How can we possibly speculate on your server code. If they changed something on the server then of course they could have broken something. Whats Lamba got to do with anything

4) If the push token becomes invalid and your app does not send the new one to the server then push would not work for whatever devices have stale tokens

5) How can this be answered when you have not yet determined the cause.

If push has *suddenly* stopped for every device then either the push certificate is invalid or the server code has changed and broken something.

If push has stopped for just some devices then its likely that either your app is not sending a new token to the server when the token changes, or it is but your server is ignoring it and using old tokens.

If push has never ever worked for an app store build (which you are positively sure is an app store build) then either your server is sending pushes on the sandbox environment and not the production environment, or apns is not enabled for production and neither your nor anybody in your company ever tested pushes with a production build and production push environment before submitting to the app store.